# how to check permission for the parent folder of a given file in bash

Tags: bash, find, output

I have this command stored in this variable:

```
filelist=$(find $dir_name -size $sizeFileTmp -printf '%M %n %u %g %-s %Tb %Td %Tk:%TM %P\n')
echo "$filelist" | sort -rnk5 | awk '{printf "%s %s %s %s %6s %3s %2s %5s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9}'
```

that produce this output:

```
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 135838 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir2/testdir2/subdir2/phones
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 135838 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir2/testdir2/phones
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 135838 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir1/testdir1/subdir1/phones
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 135838 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir1/testdir1/phones
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa 135838 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir1/.phones
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa  26615 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir2/vimtutor
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa  26615 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir2/testdir2/vimtutor
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa  26615 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir2/testdir2/subdir2/vimtutor
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa  26615 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir1/vimtutor
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa  26615 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir1/testdir1/vimtutor
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa  26615 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir1/testdir1/subdir1/vimtutor
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa  25557 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir2/testdir2/subdir2/cdlist
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa  25557 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir2/testdir2/cdlist
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa  25557 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir2/cdlist
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa  25557 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir1/testdir1/subdir1/cdlist
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa  25557 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir1/testdir1/cdlist
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa  25557 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir1/cdlist
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa  20558 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir2/testdir2/subdir2/sample.txt
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa  20558 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir2/testdir2/sample.txt
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa  20558 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir2/sample.txt
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa  20558 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir1/testdir1/subdir1/sample.txt
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa  20558 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir1/testdir1/sample.txt
-rwx------ 1 juanpa juanpa  20558 Nov 04 20:47 sample.dir1/sample.txt
```

My question is how should I check if the folder containing these files DO NOT have write and execute permission and then highlight those lines????

thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify what you consider to be the "last folder".

Comment: Thanks for comment in my question, is it better now?

Comment: depending on your need, if it's just a quick check , `echo "${filelist}" | grep -v '^.r.x'` will show you files that are not at least `-r-x------`. Good luck.

Comment: that would only work with the file, not for the container folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command can identify directories under $dir without read/write permissions, but does not restrict the reporting to folders that might have been excluded by the `-size` predicate use to generate the list:

```
find $dir -type d ! \( -readable -a -writable \) -printf '%p\n'
```

The following seems rather convoluted, but it prepends "!" to "highlight" items that do not have a user-readable/writable directory (although one might ask how one got the file listing if read permissions on the folder were not present).

```
filelist=$(find $dir_name -size $sizeFileTmp -printf '%M %n %u %g %-s %Tb %Td %Tk:%TM %P\n')
if [ -z "${filelist}" ];
then
  echo "No files."
else
  echo "$filelist" | \
  sort -rnk5 | \
  awk \
    '{ DIR = gensub(/[/][^/]*$/, "", "", $9);
       CMD = "stat -c +%A " DIR;
       CMD | getline PERMS;
       if (PERMS !~ /^..rw/)
       {
         printf("!");
       }
       printf("%s %s %s %s %6s %3s %2s %5s %s\n", \
         $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9);
    }' -
fi
```

This doesn't check every level of the directory, but only the leaf folder.

Thanks to F. Hauri for the idea to use `stat`.

Comment: Thanks kbulgrien for your answer, but there is a bug, and I don't know how to solve it
here is the output [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38105514/output.txt)

Comment: I tested the script quite thoroughly here, and it does in fact detect directories without write permissions, though as I said, one can hardly expect it to detect folders without read permissions as the find you supplied cannot find files in folders that have no read permissions.  I cannot access your link as it is blocked on this network.

Comment: I did just copy paste the script from this post and retest.  It did work, but a check was added to be sure there are actually files to process as it output only ! if dir or sizeFileTmp were not set.

Comment: your code does work, what I meant by bug is that promt this message: "stat: cannot stat `sample.dir2/testdir2': No such file or directory" between some lines this is the output: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38105514/output.txt  Thanks once again,

Comment: I cannot access dl.dropbox.com from my network.  I have a hard time guessing what the issue is, other than perhaps that you want to squelch stderr messages.  Changing `fi` to `fi 2>/dev/null` might help as long as you believe stderr will not potentially have other messages on it that you might want to see.

Comment: I fixed the bug I was talking about, something in my code. now I have a different one. inside awk I have: 
> printf("%s %s\n", PERMS, DIR);
for the first 5 lines PERMS shows the real value, but after that shows -rwx------ for all folder including those with -r-x------